# Two menu items missing from magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

Don't know when this happened. Suddenly I just noticed that two menus "mobile" and "newsletter" are missing from magento admin panel. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the modules possibly disabled in the app/etc/modules folder? 
A cache clean would then have happened (later) to make them suddenly disappear.

If they are enabled, check file permissions.

Comment: i know the module for newsletter and just figured out that it was disabled. which module is responsible for "mobile" menu

Comment: not sure. grep the modules folder files for false, should yield a result.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that somehow you are not allowed to view them anymore. Check System -> Rights -> Users/Roles to check if you have the rights to view those tabs.